# How to push array to nested child object of only matching parent properties?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-scope

Below is my JSON structure:

```
$scope.dataList = [{
   CompanyName: null,
   Location: null,
   Client: {
      ClientId: 0,
      ClientName: null,
      Projects:{
         Id: 0,
         Name: null,
      }
   }
}];
```

I have this data in dataList scope variable :

```
[{
   CompanyName: XXXX,
   Location: California,
   Client:{
      ClientId: 1,
      ClientName: John Cena,
      Projects:{
         Id: 1,
         Name: Abc,
         }
      }
}]
```

Now in the above record I need to find by company name and location and add Client array to matched company.

Now based on **button click** event I am getting 1 or more another record from http call like below:

```
[{
   CompanyName: XXXX,
   Location: California,
   Client:[{
      ClientId: 2,
      ClientName: Undertaker,
      Projects:{
         Id: 2,
         Name: Pqr,
      }
   }]
}]
```

Now I want to append this new client data to my dataList object for company XXXX and for location California.

This is how I am trying but I am getting errors:

```
$http.get("Url")
    .then(function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) // when there will be more than 1 records in response i get from http call
                {
                        var result = $.grep($scope.dataList, function (e) 
                        {
                            //find records from dataList by Company name and Location
                            return (e.CompanyName == data[i].CompanyName) && (e.Location == data[i].Location);
                        });
                        //Push client Id 2 record in dataList
                        result.Client.push(data[i]);// error:result.Client is undefined
                        console.log(result);
                }
    });
```

Comment: $scope.dataList[0].Client is an object, not an array. You are trying to push something into an object.

Comment: Additionally you are not checking if there actually is a record with matching CompanyName and Location. That's the error it gives you, because your $.grep didnt find anything and therfor result is undefined.

Comment: @user2415266 I am getting record in result variable.i have checked in console

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking, as those will help you get more and better answers from the community. Edit your question, post logs, details, server errors, etc, anything and everything you have of information, we dont need to guess on. This way, we can actually point in a better direction for you.

Comment: @Bonatti I have posted every possible detail that I have with me.can you please tell me what is the thing which is missing or unclear to you.Asking questions are now becoming difficult day by day on SO as some very few users always find  some flaw in question.sorry I am not being rude but faced this situation before when in some of the question I posted every possible details then I was told that please shorten your question etc etc... :)

Comment: I can tell you are not an "English speaking person", I am not one as well. Whenever you writte: `This is how i am trying but getting error:` we, ***the people willing and able to help you***, have to guess what "error", you are getting. Since this appears to be a JavaScript issue, a single misinterpretation in the script engine of your code will stop all execution, we cannot tell what/how to help. I can read in your question, several "impossible" features, such as incorrect JSON (`,}`) is syntactically incorrect), your `$grep`usage can be empty, so check the var length before proceding, etc...

Comment: @Bonatti: thanks for posting the Stack Overflow help links on this question. A useful tip: if you use `[ask]` or `[mcve]` in comments, they expand to the full links, without having to go and find them to paste in. It's very useful if you need to post these on a frequent basis.

Comment: @halfer Thank you, I did not know that, I usually keep a txt file here, with repeatable comments, then alter whatever is needed for the problem.... like a `new Comment(Flags.WTF).custom(String custom).toString()` .... then I think to myself, too much code, not enough human compassion....

Comment: @Bonatti: heh! Yes, it's hard to strike the right balance. As a result of automated searches I run, I get to see all manner of begging, pleading, txtspk, free-labour, too-broad and zero-effort questions, so it is easy to feel defeated. Perhaps I should scroll through a feed of excellent questions, to keep my spirits up `:=)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a check and move the content of `Client` into an array, before pushing to `result.Client`

```
if (!Array.isArray(result.Client)) { // check if not an array
    result.Client = [result.Client]; // create one with the actual content
}
result.Client.push(data[i]);
```

Comment: Not getting new client record inside client array.new client array is pushed outside of Client array